# Drupal 8: How to retrieve field values when i use loadMultiple to load multiple node ids

Tags: nodes, entities

I am loading multiple node ids like below

```
$node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->loadMultiple($nids);
foreach ($node_storage as $node){
  $value = $node->get('field_merchant_id')->value;
}
```

After this, I am getting an object and I don't know how to access my values. I have used `get('field_name')->value` but its saying `Error: Call to a member function get() on array`. How can I get an array that contains all values of one specific column from all nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do like

```
$node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);
foreach ($node_storage as $node){
   $field_merchant_id = $node->get('field_merchant_id')->value;
}
```

Here you are using "user" which should be replaced by "node" to access node values.
And also to access "field_merchant_id", you need to get that from $node.

Comment: This is actually what I had done and got that error, sorry about that mistake, i have edited my question

Comment: Try like above code. It should work and just pass $nids as node id's